# ¿Porque el metodo save devuelve los Entitys hijos como null y no con información?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Estoy creando un metodo para guardar un registro en JPA con SpringBoot. Cuando uso el método save, el registro se crea correctamente y sin problemas, el detalle es que la clase de la Entity tiene joins con otras Entitys y al usar el save no se recuperan automáticamente, en su lugar los atributos vienen como null.

Esto no sucede si consulto el ID de ese registro desde otro endpoint luego de su creacion, el meotodo finById si retorna los joins con información.

Adjunto el código de creación:

```
        if(request.getIdUser() == null)
            throw new ExceptionGS(AlertMessages.notIdUserVacationSendAlert, null);
        if(request.getInitialYearPeriod() == null)
            throw new ExceptionGS(AlertMessages.notInitialYearSendAlert, null);
        if(request.getStartDateSelected() == null)
            throw new ExceptionGS(AlertMessages.notStartDateSendAlert, null);
        if(request.getEndDateSelected() == null)
            throw new ExceptionGS(AlertMessages.notEndDateSendAlert, null);
        if(request.getDaysToEnjoySelected() == null)
            throw new ExceptionGS(AlertMessages.notDaysToEnjoySelectdSendAlert, null);
        if(request.getUserSignature() == null)
            throw new ExceptionGS(AlertMessages.notSignatureUserRequestSendAlert, null);
        if(getActiveRequestUser(request.getIdUser()) != null)
            throw new ExceptionGS(AlertMessages.alreadyActiveRequestVacationAlert, null);
        
        request.setDateToRequest(LocalDateTime.now());
        request.setEndYearPeriod(request.getInitialYearPeriod().plusYears(1));
        request.setDateReturnToWork(request.getEndDateSelected().plusDays(1));
        request.setIdUserMod(request.getIdUser());
        request.setDateMod(LocalDateTime.now());
        request.setStatus(new Long(1));
        
        UserEntity infoUser = userService.getUserById(request.getIdUser()); 
        Long codEmpBoss =  infoUser.getInfoEmployee().getCodEmp();
        
        if(infoUser.getInfoEmployee().getCodEmpBoss() != null)
            codEmpBoss=infoUser.getInfoEmployee().getCodEmpBoss();
        
  
        EmployeeEntity infoEmpBoss = empService.getInfoEmployeeByCodEmp(codEmpBoss);
        
        if(infoEmpBoss == null)
            throw new ExceptionGS(AlertMessages.notEmpBossFoundAlert, null);
        
        UserEntity infoUserBoss = userService.getUserByIdEmp(infoEmpBoss.getIdEmployee());
        
        if(infoUserBoss == null)
            throw new ExceptionGS(AlertMessages.notUserExistsToBossVacationAlert, null);
        
        request.setIdUserBossAsigned(infoUserBoss.getIdUser());
   
        VacationEntity createdRequest = vacationRepo.save(request);
        VacationEntity loadedRequest = vacationRepo.findById(createdRequest.getIdRequest()).orElse(null);

        return loadedRequest;
    }
```

La clase de Entity:

```
@Table(name = "vacation")
@Getter
@Setter
public class VacationEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
    private Long idRequest;
     
    private Long idUser; 
    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUser", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UserEntity infoUser; 
    private LocalDateTime dateToRequest;
    private Year initialYearPeriod;
    private Year endYearPeriod;
    private LocalDateTime startDateSelected;
    private LocalDateTime endDateSelected;
    private Long daysToEnjoySelected;
    
    @Lob
    private byte[] userSignature;
    private Long idUserBossAsigned;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUserBossAsigned", referencedColumnName = "idUser", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UserEntity infoUserBossAsigned;
    private LocalDateTime dateBossAuth;
    @Lob
    private byte[] userBossSignature; 
 
    private Long idUserFinalAuth;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUserFinalAuth", referencedColumnName = "idUser", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UserEntity infoUserFinalAuth;
    private LocalDateTime dateFinalAuth;
    
    private LocalDateTime startDateAuth;
    private LocalDateTime endDateAuth;
    private LocalDateTime dateReturnToWork;
    private Long daysToEnjoyAuth;
    
    private Long idUserMod; 
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUserMod",referencedColumnName = "idUser", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UserEntity infoUserMod;
    private LocalDateTime dateMod;
    private String observations;
    private String pdfPath;
    
    private Long status;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="status", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private CatalogStatusVacationEntity infoState;
    
}
```

La respuesta del save:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La respuesta al consultar el endpoint individual:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué he intentado?

1. Creí que el problema nacía por que aun no existe el registro a ese entonces, así que lo consulte individualmente luego del save, pero no funciona.
2. Use notaciones en la Entity como casacade ALL, y tambien persists pero no funcino

Comment: No subas tanta imagen a no ser necesario, es preferible que copies ese ejemplo y lo detalles mejor aca.